# Big Mod algorithm

Tags: pascal, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to make a Pascal program for my school programming team's online judge. The program has to output a^b mod c, where a, b and c are given as input. You cant use brute force as the test case all have very large numbers.

After some research, it turned out that I could use the divide and conquer strategy. This is the code that I came up with:

```
function pmod(a,b,c:longint):integer;
begin
     if b = 0 then
        pmod := 1;
     if b = 1 then
        pmod := a mod c;
     if b > 1 then
     begin
          if (b mod 2) = 0 then
             pmod := (pmod(a,b div 2,c) * pmod(a,b div 2,c)) mod c
          else
              pmod := (pmod(a,b-1,c) * (a mod c)) mod c;
     end;
end;
```

However, the online judge returned Wrong Answer. Could anybody point out what's the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is basically sound and should work. There are definitely a few small things that could be improved in your code, but I wouldn't call it "wrong". Lets looks at some of the possible issues.

1. Recursion. It has the advantage of keeping the algorithm simple and fairly easy to read. However it is a very slow and inefficient way to do this. Since the same basic algorithm can fairly easily be made iterative then the judge may have marked you down on this.
2. It would be a good idea to handle invalid inputs a little better. If someone entered a negative integer for "b" then no return value would be assigned to pmod. Since modulo always returns a positive result we could make a convention of returning "-1" for example as an error flag if b<0.
3. Notice that pmod returns integer, but the maximum value of the modulo is c-1, which is longint. So the size of the types used aren't necessarily compatible, unless you do some range checking. You could however guarantee no overflow of intermediate calculations if you used an integer type of twice the width of c and pmod for intermediates.

I'm not sure what pascal compiler you're using. In older (DOS) versions I think integer was 16 bit and longint was 32 bit. In Delphi both integer and longint are 32 bit and int64 is 64 bit. So depending on the compiler you could have longint for a,b and intermediates and integer for c and pmod (or in the case of newer pascal versions, int64 for a,b and intermediates and integer for c and pmod.

Here's an example of these minor improvements.

```
function pmod(a,b: int64; c:integer):integer;
var tmp: int64;
 begin
   if b < 0 then pmod := -1; {flag an error}
   if b = 0 then pmod := 1;
   if b = 1 then pmod := a mod c;
   if b > 1 then
    begin
      if (b mod 2) = 0 then
         begin
           tmp  :=pmod(a,b div 2,c) * pmod(a,b div 2,c);
           pmod := tmp mod c
         end
      else
         begin
           tmp  := pmod(a,b-1,c) * (a mod c);
           pmod := tmp mod c
         end
    end;
 end;
```